# How to estimate the best predictor?

Tags: regression, predictor

I have a continuous variable $y$. Using univariate linear regression I have tested $a, b$ and $c$ as independent variables against $y$ as a dependent variable.

I have gotten different $R^2$ and $p$-values.

- $Y + a: R^2 = 0.60, p < 0.01$
- $Y + b: R^2 = 0.20, p < 0.04$
- $Y + c: R^2 = 0.01, p = 0.06$

Out of these results I assume that $a$ is a better predictor of $y$ than $b$ and $c$. But is this really so? Do I have to do a statistic test to show this? Which/how?

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand why you're doing univariate regression when you have multiple independent variables. Multiple regression would allow you to compare their contributions to the linear model as joint predictors...Unless it's important not to enter them in the same model, I'd recommend multiple regression, first of all. Your standardized ($\beta$) coefficients will identify the predictors' relative strength, and you can calculate confidence intervals around them to quantify (somewhat indirectly) your confidence that replications of your study would not change the rank order of your predictors in terms of strength. If it is important to consider your predictors separately as univariate models, remember that $R^2 = r^2$ in the univariate case, and differences in $r$ can be tested for significance by [very simple methods](http://www.quantpsy.org/corrtest/corrtest.htm), or again, confidence intervals can be compared.